# Cloudfront not invalidating files for https

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have some bundled code hosted on S3 and I'm trying to compress and serve it via cloudfront. This is working fine HOWEVER when I try to make any changes to the code it won't update. I've tried invalidating the file specifically as well as invalidating everything via the wildcard path /*. Nothing works. Interestingly, the file IS invalidated when I try to access it via http. But, as I'm trying to have SSL working on my site, I need to access it with https. I've even gone so far as to delete the file from my S3 bucket but nope, it's still available over https. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl + shift + r` or `cmd + shift + r` will do a hard reload (clearing cache on your browser)

I also suggest having a cache busting strategy, like adding a hash to the name of the bundle every time it updates.

There's a way to add a hash through `webpack`, check more [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)

Comment: This might be helpful advice but does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it had something to do with my browsers cache or something. It worked fine on a different computer